# Не создается двумерный массив! Python3

Tags: python, массивы, python-3.x

Мне нужно создать двумерный массив, но почему-то мой код не работает. В сам массив элементы добавляются (в цикле), но если попытаться вывести его через `print` после цикла, ничего не происходит.

```
 def sub_open(path_rar, path_corp):
    if not os.path.exists(path_corp):
       os.makedirs(path_corp)
    for root,dirs,files in os.walk(path_rar):
        for folder in dirs:
           print(folder)
           file = file_corp(path_corp, folder)
           alligns = allign_times('.//Extracted_Data//', folder, file)
           print(alligns) - здесь тоже ничего не выводит((((


def allign_times(path_rar, folder, sub_corpus):
   alligns = []
   for root,dirs,files in os.walk(path_rar + folder + '//'):
        for file in files:
           print(file) ############
           sub_file = open(path_rar + folder + '//' + file,  'r').read()
           times = re.findall('\d\d:\d\d:\d\d,\d\d\d --> \d\d:\d\d:\d\d,\d\d\d', sub_file)
           data_times, data_reverse = transform(times) ##
           vals = [i for i in sorted(list(data_times.values()))]
           vals1 = [i for i in sorted(list(data_times.keys()))]
           allphrases = piece_to_file(data_times, sub_file, times, vals, data_reverse, vals1)##
           #print(allphrases)   - тут находятся элементы и выводятся
           alligns.append(allphrases) - вроде как добавляем
           #print(alligns)    - тут печатает 

    #print(alligns) - выходим из цикла и после принта вообще ничего не выводит
    return alligns
```

Как решить эту проблему? Где ошибка? Как сделать так, чтобы выводился нормальный двумерный массив, когда вызываешь функцию внутри функции `sub_open`?
Буду благодарен за ответ!

Comment: Сам массив allphrases довольно объемный получается, но это же не причина..

Comment: попробуй сделать принт среза или просто его длины. Там где работает принт попробуй поставить в верхнем цикле

Comment: у тебя except не вываливался???

Comment: Убедитесь, что вы видите stderr: `import sys; print("stderr", file=sys.stderr); print("stdout")`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Вы должны создать массив `alligns` вне тела функции, так как сейчас это - локальная переменная функции `allign_times`.
Объявите её в самом начале файла (до функций), и в каждой из них в первой строчке напишите `global alligns`.

Comment: из бегайте ненужных глобальных переменных (как в этом случае). Обратите внимание, что `alligns` возвращается из `allign_times`. Имя `alligns` в `sub_open()` не связано c именем `alligns` в `allign_times()` (можно другое имя использовать). Оба имени локальные.